# Regex pattern for simple text

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text that I converted from a PDF file, and I now need to take specific contents from the text using regex. In the past I used indexes, and math to get a specific length

This is my text:

```
1ZW6897X0327621544
```

Each one will start with `1Z` and be 18 characters long.

I have tried going to Regexr.com to help but it just does not make any sense at all:

```
1Z[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

This is how my brain is processing what I am reading, `1Z` is the start and then any character `0-9` for the next 16 places?

Can some one please help.

Comment: That regex doesn't capture the tracking number.  You're looking for 0-9, but the number clearly includes letters.

Comment: This might be weird.. But theres a developer/reporting manager that has the same name as you except with an IA in bryan

Comment: sorry to hear he spells it wrong :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
\b1Z[A-Z0-9]{16}\b
```

Or

```
\b1Z\w{16}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z4JP4a/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `1Z` - a literal substring
- `[A-Z0-9]{16}` - 16 uppercase ASCII letters and/or digits (note that `\w` will match any letters, digits, and/or `_` and if you do not pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`, it will match all Unicode letters/digits, and some more "funny" symbols)
- `\b` - a word boundary.

If the boundaries are whitespace (i.e. the matches are expected to be preceded with start of string or whitespace and followed with the end of string or whitespace), you may use `(?<!\S)1Z[A-Z0-9]{16}(?!\S)` pattern instead.

In C#, you may use it with `Regex.Matches`:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\b1Z[A-Z0-9]{16}\b")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: And so if I wanted to match 6487941852A where the A can be optional, my pattern would be \b[0-9]{10}A* ... Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: @Bluestreak22 Probably, you'd use `@"\b[0-9]{10}A?\b"` (if `A` can appear 1 or 0 times). `*` means 0 or more.

Comment: Why do i need a closing \b?

Comment: That is a word boundary. If you do not need whole word matching, discard it.